# What temporary memory is gzip using?

Tags: linux, gzip

When using gzip (in linux environment) to compress a file, it compresses a file, then removes the orignal. What memory is it using or where is it putting the compressed file until its finished?

Example: I have an embedded linux system operating on a disk with two partitions, one root partition for the filesystem and one partition just for data. When the data partition is 100% full, I can still gzip a file on it. How is this possible if gzip is not temporarily using space on the root partition? How can i find out what directory it is using?

Edit: (Added df output)
root@qemuarm:/opt/hdisk# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        1007896  110488    846208  12% /
devtmpfs          118880       4    118876   1% /dev
/dev/sda2        2826800 2695424         0 100% /opt/hdisk
tmpfs             118960      76    118884   1% /run
tmpfs             118960       4    118956   1% /var/volatile/tmp

Comment: It could work in memory, or using some `tmpfs` file system

Comment: gzip wriites to to a file in the same folder as the original, but with a .gz extension. Don't forget that the root user normally also have a few percent disk space reserved - when the filesystem indicates it is full - it's actually not.

Comment: So what would the error mean, when gzip reports "Error, no space left on device?". Thats what I'm expecting to see, however i dont, the uncompressed file is removed and replaced with the compressed instead.

Comment: @user3821741 As mentioned, there are extra space reserved for the root user. When you see that the drive is 100% full, it is not really true. There are a few percent left that only the root user can use. That might be what you are observing. Did you then try to run gzp as another user instead of the root user ?
How big is your file ? How much space does it take up when it's compressed ? Could your filesystem be 99.6% full (which will be displayed as 100% full), and your compressed file really just needs that 0.4% of space ?

Comment: Added df output  to original post, it looks like @user3821741 is correct, that while it displays 100% full, it is really only using 2695424/2826800... which is only about 95% despite df saying 100%

Answer (score 2):

gzip never keeps the entire compressed file in memory. Only a few K bytes is kept, as the compressed data is being generated. gzip writes the .gz file as it is generated, to the same directory as the original file. Only after that is successful (or at least appears successful to gzip) is the original file deleted.

I have no idea why your "100% full" file system is permitting the write, but apparently 100% doesn't really mean 100%. You could just try writing a file with junk, to see how much you need to write before it complains about a full disk.